# Find a particular integral of $y=\frac{1}{D^2+4D+5}x.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a particular integral of $y=\frac{1}{D^2+4D+5}x.$

I tried solving it like this:

> Given, $y=\frac{1}{D^2+4D+5}x.$ So, we can say, $$y=\frac{1}{D^2+4D+5}x\implies y=\frac{1}{4D}(\frac D4+\frac{5}{4D}+1)^{-1}x=\frac{1}{4D}(1-\frac D4-\frac{5}{4D}+\frac{D^2}{16}+\frac{25}{16D^2}+....$$

But this is where the problem lies. I dont have to worry about the terms of the form  $D^n$ where $n\geq 2$ as then $D^n(x)=0$ but the problem lies for the terms of the form $\frac{1}{D^n},n\in\Bbb Z,$ in the infinite series. How should I go on evaluating  this? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: My gut instinct would be to try partial fraction decomposition and the geometric series and see how that pans out.

Comment: @PrincessEev But still I face the problem there as well for : $(D^2+4D+5)=(D+2+i)(D+2-i)$ . Thus, whotsoever, decomposing into partial fractions, we have to evaluate say, terms like this: $\frac{1}{D+2+i}x$. Now, say, $$\frac{1}{D+2+i}x=p\implies Dp+(2+i)p=x.$$ This is indeed a first order linear differential equation, *with complex coefficients.* So, I don't know whether *the normal* methods for this evaluation (i.e finding integrating factor and....) like we used to do in case of a first order linear differential equation, *with real coefficients,* will be applicable or not?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\left(\frac1{1+\frac{D^2+4D}5}\right)x =\left(1-\frac{D^2+4D}5+\frac{(D^2+4D)^2}{25}-\cdots\right) x = \left(1-\frac45D\right)x$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...